# Hash Functions and Tables of size of the form 2^p

Tags: data-structures, hash

While calculating the hash table bucket index from the hash code of a key, why do we avoid use of remainder after division (modulo) when the size of the array of buckets is a power of 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calculating the hash, you want as much information as you can cheaply munge things into with good distribution across the entire range of bits: e.g. 32-bit unsigned integers are usually good, unless you have a lot (>3 billion) of items to store in the hash table.

It's converting the hash code into a bucket index that you're really interested in. When the number of buckets n is a power of two, all you need to do is do an AND operation between hash code h and (n-1), and the result is equal to h mod n.

A reason this may be bad is that the AND operation is simply discarding bits - the high-level bits - from the hash code. This may be good or bad, depending on other things. On one hand, it will be very fast, since AND is a lot faster than division (and is the usual reason why you would choose to use a power of 2 number of buckets), but on the other hand, poor hash functions may have poor entropy in the lower bits: that is, the lower bits don't change much when the data being hashed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that the table size is m = 2^p.
Let k be a key.
Then, whenever we do k mod m, we will only get the last p bits of the binary representation of k. Thus, if I put in several keys that have the same last p bits, the hash function will perform VERY VERY badly as all keys will be hashed to the same slot in the table. Thus, avoid powers of 2

Comment: hey, do you think my answer does not answer ur question?